# The "size" argument must be of type number

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, webusb

I've got a problem with sending a transferOut to my USB device in my Electron application.

Here is the code where the problem occurs:

```
async sendDataToDevice(device) {
    const data = new Uint16Array(16);
    data[0] = 3333;
    
    await device.transferOut(0x81, data);
}
```

this code throws for me not yet known reason this error:
**Error: transferOut error: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "size" argument must be of type number. Received an instance of Buffer**

**Additional Information**

- Operating System: Windows 10
- Node.js version: v14.16.1
- Node USB Version (npm ls usb): 2.4.3

Comment: never worked with it but it is quite clear that what you are passing to `transferOut` in the first argument is a Buffer and not a number. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/USBDevice/transferOut

Comment: This probably won't be the problem, because if I use device.transferIn(0x81, 48) function with exactly the same first parameter, this error regarding the size won't show up and it works properly.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it may be a bug in the node-usb library. The `transferOut` method is supposed to take an endpoint number and a buffer, not a size. That error doesn't make any sense unless for some reason the argument validation code for `transferIn` and `transferOut` is mixed up. The `transferIn` method is the one that takes a size.